# what's the way to explicitly provide memory to shell script?

Tags: memory, shell

How can I give a shell script specific amount of memory to run? If I run a java program I can use -Xmx. But what if it is a shell script?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into limiting the available memory with `ulimit -m XXX` (see `ulimit -a` for current settings and available options). It's not a question of "giving memory to a shell script" but "limiting the maximum memory".

Comment: actually i notice every time i run "top" that it gets a specific amount of memory and wondered if i can tell the shell to allocate more memory for it...